# Nested settings in ssh config for domains and aliased subdomains

Tags: ssh, alias, domain, ssh-config

How can I have rules for a whole domain and also create aliases with rules for each of the subdomains without duplicating all the ruleset?

In other words, why is it that in the following example `boomerang` is not used as the default user when I try to ssh into `mega.micro.ws` by invoking `ssh mega`? And is there a correct and parsimonious way to achieve this using ssh config and/or the rest of the available ssh toolset?

```
Host mega
    HostName mega.micro.ws
    RemoteForward 52698 localhost:52698
Host *.micro.ws
    User boomerang
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally the configuration is parsed in a single pass. First all sections are checked against your input and all settings are gathered, and only after that's done, the HostName setting is actually applied.

To achieve what you want, instead of a Host section you'll need a Match section:

```
Match final host *.micro.ws
    User boomerang
```

This enables two-pass configuration loading. See the ssh_config(5) manual page for `canonical` and `final` keywords.